# Issues in using git forked package in Docker-compose

Tags: python, django, git, docker, dockerfile

I have installed one package which is forked from original package so I have installed that using

```
pip install -e git://github.com/**package**.git@7f323a3682ddede83a7bf53cdc8d24bcc24d096c#egg=**package**
```

But when I list my packages using  `docker-compose exec myapp pip list` this package is not listed here and I am unable to run my project.

Comment: Why aren't you executing pip install using docker exec as well?

Comment: There is really no need to censor the package name, when you give the commit hash.

Comment: @YaronIdan I am installing packages via Dockerfile (pip install -r requirements.txt)

Comment: @KlausD. you mean ```pip install -e git://github.com/**package**.git@7f323a3682ddede83a7bf53cdc8d24bcc24d096c```  ??